# Selecting from db2 and inserting where not exists in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, db2

This script is meant to connect to a db2 database as well as a mysql database. There is a table in the db2 database that's updated regularly and this script is meant to check it against a similar table in mysql, and if a record matching certain conditions is in the db2 table but not mysql, I will be inserting it.

As far as the query, I know that I want it to check customer name and phone number. So if a record in the db2 table has the same company name and phone number, it's ignored, but if it's a different number for the company name or a brand new record entirely, I want to insert it. I believe this needs to be done by a "Not Exists" statement.

My other issue is I'm just not sure the best way to compare the tables since they're on different connections. I'm assuming I would select from my db2 table, perhaps store that and then somehow use what was stored to base my INSERT off of.

Can someone help me craft these queries/statements to overcome those hurdles?

Example:

if Mysql table has

```
    customerName | phone
    --------------------------
    cust123         1234567890
```

And DB2 has a secondary number for the company

```
    customerName | phone
    --------------------------
    cust123         1234567890
    cust123         0987654321
```

Then I want to add the record with the 0987654321 number only since the first one already exists. Same goes for a brand new company and phone number.

```
    <?php

    //MySql Connection credentials
    $mysqlServer = "";
    $mysqlUser = "";
    $mysqlPass = "*";

    //Establilsh MySql Connection
    $mysqlConn = new mysqli($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass);

    //Check MySQL connection
    if($mysqlConn->connect_error){
      die("Connection Failed: " .$mysqlConn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected Succssfully to Mysql";


    //DB2 Connection Credentials
    $DB2Server = "";
    $DB2User = "";
    $DB2Pass = "";

    //Establish DB2 connection
    $DB2Conn = odbc_connect("","", "");

    //Check DB2 Connection
    if(!$DB2Conn){
      die("Could not connect");
    }
    echo "Connected Succssfully to DB2";


    //First Query - Select * from db2

    /*select * from jacmfg.custmstf*/

    /*

            Insert Into 

            jfi.ambition_customer_data (companyNumber, customerName, phone, email)
            Select (db2 values) from db2 
            Where
                Not Exists (customerName(db2) = customerName(mysql), phone(db2) = phone(mysql))

    */



    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing the db2 data in php variables, consider copying the entire table of customer names and phone numbers into MySQL for this comparison and update.  You might do that by shuffling the data through php, but it would very likely be faster if you exported it from db2 to a CSV file and then used MySQL's `load data local infile` command to import the data from that CSV file.

Then, assuming that your table of customer data in MySQL is named `customer_table`, and the data imported from db2 is in a staging table named `staging`, you can insert new records from the db2 table into the MySQL table as follows:

```
insert into customer_table
    (customerName, phone)
select
    s.customerName,
    s.phone
from
    staging as s
    left join customer_table as c
        on c.customerName=s.customerName
        and c.phone=s.phone
where
    c.customerName is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but since they are on 2 different connections and the db2 table could be updated several times per day, how would I then be able to check for those updates after the dump from db2? I did dump the whole table and import it into mysql, this process is just for the future to add anything that might get updated

Comment: If you need to perform a check like this at high frequency throughout the day, and exporting the entire table would be too costly, then you may want to create a trigger on the db2 table that either copies new rows into another table to be exported periodically, or exports each row immediately, and use a daemon or system task to check for these updates at the desired frequency and then pull them into MySQL to do the comparison/update.  Edits and deletions would have to be handled similarly.

Comment: Hmm that's where I'm not sure, since this is in testing stages. The main data is already there, which we did via a large import. The issue is a customer might be added to the db2 side tomorrow, or there may not be an update for weeks. I was just hoping to make a script to run daily that would check for any updates that aren't in the mysql table

Comment: The 'best' approach depends at least in part on the size of your customer table.  If you only need to run the check once per day and the table isn't too large, the method outlined in my answer is likely to be simplest to implement.  If the table is extremely large, then using triggers so that you only need to export new or edited rows may be preferable in terms of overall performance, but would take more effort to implement.